# How to convert complex React class component to functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a `React.Component` that uses a lot of its features to a functional component. I'm not sure how many of these pieces can be converted without breaking existing functionality. Here is what my class looks like:

```js
export default class Dapp extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  provider!: Web3Provider;

  contract!: NftContractType;

  private merkleProofManualAddressInput!: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = defaultState;
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const browserProvider = await detectEthereumProvider() as ExternalProvider;
    this.provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(browserProvider);
    this.registerWalletEvents(browserProvider);
    await this.initWallet();
  }

  private isContractReady(): boolean {
    return this.contract !== undefined;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.isWalletConnected() ?
          <>
            {this.isContractReady() ?
              <>
                <CollectionStatus
                  userAddress={this.state.userAddress}
                  maxSupply={this.state.maxSupply}
                  totalSupply={this.state.totalSupply}
                  isPaused={this.state.isPaused}
                  isWhitelistMintEnabled={this.state.isWhitelistMintEnabled}
                  isUserInWhitelist={this.state.isUserInWhitelist}
                />
          </>
        : <div>Connected</div>}
      </>
    );
  }

  private async initWallet(): Promise<void> {
    const walletAccounts = await this.provider.listAccounts();
    
    this.setState(defaultState);

    if (walletAccounts.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    const network = await this.provider.getNetwork();
    let networkConfig: NetworkConfigInterface;

    if (network.chainId === CollectionConfig.mainnet.chainId) {
      networkConfig = CollectionConfig.mainnet;
    } else if (network.chainId === CollectionConfig.testnet.chainId) {
      networkConfig = CollectionConfig.testnet;
    } else {
      this.setError('Unsupported network!');

      return;
    }
    
    this.setState({
      userAddress: walletAccounts[0],
      network,
      networkConfig,
    });

    if (await this.provider.getCode(CollectionConfig.contractAddress!) === '0x') {
      this.setError('Could not find the contract, are you connected to the right chain?');

      return;
    }

    this.contract = new ethers.Contract(
      CollectionConfig.contractAddress!,
      ContractAbi,
      this.provider.getSigner(),
    ) as unknown as NftContractType;

    this.setState({
      maxSupply: (await this.contract.maxSupply()).toNumber(),
      totalSupply: (await this.contract.totalSupply()).toNumber(),
      maxMintAmountPerTx: (await this.contract.maxMintAmountPerTx()).toNumber(),
      tokenPrice: await this.contract.cost(),
      isPaused: await this.contract.paused(),
      isWhitelistMintEnabled: await this.contract.whitelistMintEnabled(),
      isUserInWhitelist: Whitelist.contains(this.state.userAddress ?? ''),
    });
  }
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to convert `componentDidMount` to a function. These are just some of the pieces, but enough to help me get through the rest. Thanks for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` can be replaced with `useEffect` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html